# Prim MST with Adjacency Matrix as parameter

Tags: c, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I'm working with Prim MST in C and the function takes an adjacency matrix. Given the weight of course in `A[i][j]`.

Suppose I have a predecessor array that tracks down the minimum edges i Have found so far.
`predecessor[u]=v` {this is also the final MST}

Now I want to modify the current `A[i][j]` matrix and change the weights to 1. 
That is when the edges (indexes) also existed in the predecessor array.
Otherwise I change it to zero.

How would I do it? Here's my solution:

```
for (x....)
   for (y...)
      if (x!=y && (p[x]==y || p[y]==x))
         set to 1
      else
         set to 0
```

Comment: that looks right... What's your actual question?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what else to check :S How would you do it?

Comment: exactly the way you did... or possibly as in the answer by sdcwc

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudocode is correct, this will give you a 0-1 matrix which represents the tree found by Prim's algorithm. However, this method of storage is rather expensive, since it requires O(n^2) space, while a tree can be stored in O(n) memory.

Alternatively, you can initialize the matrix to zeroes in O(n^2) and then add edges in O(n) time:

```
 for (x ...)
    for (y ...)
       A[x][y] = 0

 for (x ...)
    if (p[x] != x)
      A[x][p[x]] = A[p[x]][x] = 1
```